# Maven resolver at Jenkins job with Arquillian tests (Issue when creating WAR by ShrinkWrap)

Tags: jenkins, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to do a little modular project that uses Arquillian tests remotely launched on WildFly 8.1.0 server. Everything is wirking, but only when i launch tests from my IDE. When Jenkins tries to do the same, it fails with error:

```
SEVERE [domain.testframework.logic.UserPersistTest] : org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.Invokable$InvocationException: Unable to invoke onlyOne([Ljava.lang.Class;@5d79653) on object org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.spi.loader.ServiceRegistry with parameters [Ljava.lang.Object;@cce2624
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.Invokable.invokeMethod(Invokable.java:108) [shrinkwrap-resolver-api-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.ResolverSystemFactory.createFromUserView(ResolverSystemFactory.java:91) [shrinkwrap-resolver-api-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.ResolverSystemFactory.createFromUserView(ResolverSystemFactory.java:53) [shrinkwrap-resolver-api-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.Resolvers.use(Resolvers.java:68) [shrinkwrap-resolver-api-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.Maven.resolver(Maven.java:36) [shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at domain.testframework.logic.UserPersistTest.createDeployment(UserPersistTest.java:61) [:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.invoke(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:177) [arquillian-container-test-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.generateDeployment(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:103) [arquillian-container-test-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.generate(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:64) [arquillian-container-test-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.DeploymentGenerator.generateDeployment(DeploymentGenerator.java:79) [arquillian-container-test-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94) [arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99) [arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81) [arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145) [arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116) [arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67) [arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:100) [arquillian-container-test-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94) [arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99) [arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81) [arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:84) [arquillian-test-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94) [arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88) [arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65) [arquillian-test-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94) [arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88) [arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145) [arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116) [arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:80) [arquillian-test-impl-base-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:190) [arquillian-junit-core-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:345) [arquillian-junit-core-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:49) [arquillian-junit-core-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:207) [arquillian-junit-core-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309) [junit-4.11.jar:]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:155) [arquillian-junit-core-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264) [surefire-junit4-2.17.jar:2.17]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153) [surefire-junit4-2.17.jar:2.17]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124) [surefire-junit4-2.17.jar:2.17]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200) [surefire-booter-2.17.jar:2.17]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153) [surefire-booter-2.17.jar:2.17]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) [surefire-booter-2.17.jar:2.17]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.Invokable.invokeMethod(Invokable.java:100) [shrinkwrap-resolver-api-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new service instance
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.spi.loader.SpiServiceLoader.createInstance(SpiServiceLoader.java:248) [shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.spi.loader.SpiServiceLoader.createInstances(SpiServiceLoader.java:208) [shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.spi.loader.SpiServiceLoader.all(SpiServiceLoader.java:79) [shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.spi.loader.SpiServiceLoader.onlyOne(SpiServiceLoader.java:85) [shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.spi.loader.ServiceRegistry.onlyOne(ServiceRegistry.java:117) [shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.spi.loader.SpiServiceLoader.createInstance(SpiServiceLoader.java:244) [shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.InvalidConfigurationFileException: Unable to get security configuration from /root/.m2/settings-security.xml. Please define path to the settings-security.xml file via -Dorg.apache.maven.security-settings, or put it the the default location defined by Maven.
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.internal.decrypt.MavenSecurityDispatcher.getMaster(MavenSecurityDispatcher.java:171) [shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.internal.decrypt.MavenSecurityDispatcher.decrypt(MavenSecurityDispatcher.java:96) [shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.internal.decrypt.MavenSettingsDecrypter.decrypt(MavenSettingsDecrypter.java:92) [shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.internal.decrypt.MavenSettingsDecrypter.decrypt(MavenSettingsDecrypter.java:60) [shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.bootstrap.MavenSettingsBuilder.decryptPasswords(MavenSettingsBuilder.java:223) [shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.bootstrap.MavenSettingsBuilder.buildSettings(MavenSettingsBuilder.java:186) [shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.bootstrap.MavenSettingsBuilder.buildDefaultSettings(MavenSettingsBuilder.java:113) [shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenWorkingSessionImpl.<init>(MavenWorkingSessionImpl.java:136) [shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenResolverSystemImpl.<init>(MavenResolverSystemImpl.java:44) [shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    ... 74 more
```

**@Deployment method**

```
@Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        File pom = new File("pom.xml");
        LOG.info("---->>" + pom);

        File[] libs = null;
        try {
            libs = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile(pom)
                    .importRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();
        } catch (Throwable exception) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "", exception);
        }
        LOG.info("LIBS RESOLVED: " + libs.length);
        for (File lib : libs) {
            System.out.println(lib);
        }
        WebArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "ShrinkWrap-arquillian-test.war")
                .addAsWebInfResource("web.xml")
                .addClass(User.class)
                .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

        for (File lib : libs) {
            if (!lib.toString().contains("test-framework-data")) {
                archive.addAsLibrary(lib);
            }
        }
    }
```

any idea why this is happening?

my parent POM

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-framework-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>test-framework-web</module>
        <module>test-framework-logic</module>
        <module>test-framework-data</module>
        <module>test-framework-ear</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <!--Wersje pluginów-->
        <ejb-plugin-version>2.3</ejb-plugin-version>
        <war-plugin-version>2.4</war-plugin-version>
        <ear-plugin-version>2.9</ear-plugin-version>
        <compiler-plugin-version>3.1</compiler-plugin-version>
        <maven-dependency-plugin-version>2.8</maven-dependency-plugin-version>
        <!--Wersje zależności-->
        <javaee-api-version>7.0</javaee-api-version>
        <shrinkwrap.bom-version>2.1.1</shrinkwrap.bom-version>
        <postgreslq.version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</postgreslq.version>
        <!--Wersja EJB-->
        <ejb-spec-version>3.2</ejb-spec-version>
        <!--Wersje środowiska testowego-->
        <surefire-plugin-version>2.17</surefire-plugin-version>
        <junit-version>4.11</junit-version>
        <arquillian-version>1.1.5.Final</arquillian-version>
        <wildfly-version>8.1.0.Final</wildfly-version>
        <arquillian-wildfly-version>8.1.0.Final</arquillian-wildfly-version>
        <arquillian-transaction-version>1.0.1.Final</arquillian-transaction-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>${javaee-api-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${shrinkwrap.bom-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
                <version>${shrinkwrap.bom-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-transaction-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${arquillian-transaction-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.0.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${arquillian-version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>${postgreslq.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${ear-plugin-version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-dependency-plugin-version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire-plugin-version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${compiler-plugin-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java-version}</source>
                        <target>${java-version}</target>
                        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${ejb-plugin-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <ejbVersion>${ejb-spec-version}</ejbVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${war-plugin-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/web.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <name>test-framework</name>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to this problem was a bit trivial. 
Problem was with the settings.xml for maven repository. I have local repository with credentials like `<password>{123}abc</password>`.

Maven.resolver() requires modification to `<password>\{123\}abc</password>` otherwise it will look for file 'settings-security.xml'. I've modified local copy of this file, however on server it was not changed.